# No sound driver in GNOME sound applet

Tags: 14.04, gnome, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

I cannot see anymore any sound device in the GNOME sound applet, after updating Ubuntu 14.04 (the update contained the kernel 3.13.0-49). I tried to come back to the preceding kernel (3.13.0-48) without effect. The consequence is that I cannot choose anymore the HDMI sound output. However, the sound keeps working fine (!) with the computer's audio speakers and with headphones. Any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot

Comment: The screenshot is in French, look at the window on the left: nothing ! I can see a list of sound devices by using VLC. However, the connexion with the pulseaudio server fails when I start VLC.

Comment: Run aplay -l is it listed here ?

Comment: aplay -l displays CA0132 Analog, CA0132 Digital, HDMI 0, HDMI 1 and HDMI 2 indeed.

Comment: I replaced your screenshot in French with the same one in English, but you can change it back if it's not OK. Now that you have found the answer I would recommend leaving it in English so that everyone can understand it.

Comment: It's fine. More people will understand the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset all the pulseaudio User Configuration

```
rm - rf .config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

This file is known to get corrupted, and you said you did an upgrade so this seem plausible.

Comment: Do you still have sound

Comment: Indeed, after the update, the files in .config/pulse got corrupted for some reason. I'll try to remember for the next time :-).